# Arrays.asList().contains() giving wrong result

Tags: java, arrays, list

**Code :**

```
private static final int[] GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH = { 11, 12, 13,
            14, 15 };
Log.e(TAG, "index : "
                        + Arrays.asList(GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH).indexOf(11));

Log.e(TAG, "contains : "
                        + Arrays.asList(GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH)
                                .contains(11));
```

Above statements logs :

```
index : -1
contains : false
```

I tried for all other values too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Arrays#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) returns a *generic* type.

One solution is to change your array to `Integer` instead of `int`:

```
private static final Integer[] GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH = { 11, 12, 13,
            14, 15 };
```

See this [very useful link](http://mlangc.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/be-carefull-when-converting-java-arrays-to-lists/) I found.

---

[Arrays#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) returns `List<int[]>` and not `List<Integer>` (What you wanted - Recall that there is no such a thing `List<int>`). 
Also, it's good to mention that if an `int` is boxed to `Integer`, then be careful.. Because for example: `Integer(11)` **!=** `11`.

Comment: Shouldn't `11` autoboxed in his case?

Comment: How will this change help. Can you please explain? If he is using java 5 or above, auto boxing should take care of this.

Comment: @Ankur. `int[]` is not autoboxed to `Integer[]`. Only `int` can autobox to `Integer`.

Comment: no. autoboxing will not take care of this. look Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer

Answer (score 7):

`Arrays.asList` for `int[]` arg creates a `List<int[]>` with one element. This is why contains dont work

Answer (score 0):

You should use as follows

```
   Integer[] GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH = { 11, 12, 13,14, 15 };
   System.out.println((Arrays.asList(GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH)).indexOf(11));
   System.out.println((Arrays.asList(GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH)).contains(11));
```

Since We are define `List<Integer>` this consider about object

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
Arrays.asList(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) which was introduced in Java 8.

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(GOOGLE_DIRECTION_ID_FOR_MATCH)
                           .boxed()
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("index: " + list.indexOf(11));
System.out.println("contains: " + list.contains(11));
```